# How to override vendor\magento\framework\View\Page\Config\Renderer.php in Module

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.3, magento-framework

Thanks in advance :)

I can confirm the module is working correctly.
I have tried adding the following to the di.xml file in my module:

```
<preference for="Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Renderer" type="Vendor\Module\Framework\View\Page\Config\Renderer" />
```

And the following to my Renderer.php file in app\code\Vendor\Module\Framework\View\Page\Config:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Framework\View\Page\Config;

use Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Renderer as MagentoRenderer;

class Renderer extends MagentoRenderer
{

  /**
   * Render head content
   *
   * @return string
   */
  public function renderHeadContent()
  {
    $result = '';
    return $result;
  }
}
```

Without any effect and no entries in any log to debug.

I ***can*** make these changes directly here:

```
vendor\magento\framework\View\Page\Config\Renderer.php
```

or here

```
lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Renderer.php
```

and the changes are then visible, but for obvious reasons would like to stay away from the core and restrict my changes to modules.

I would like to start with overriding ***public function renderHeadContent***, but ultimately, I would like to modify ***protected function addDefaultAttributes***. Any advice or assistance would be appreciated, thanks!

Tried: [Magento 2: Overriding a protected function that implements another interface](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/277528/magento-2-overriding-a-protected-function-that-implements-another-interface)

Also tried: [How to override /vendor/magento/framework/Logger/Handler/system.php](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/293100/how-to-override-vendor-magento-framework-logger-handler-system-php)

Also tried: [Override framework file vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Html/Link/Current.php](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/283352/override-framework-file-vendor-magento-framework-view-element-html-link-current)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, the Developer setting was set to Client-side compilation and this was preventing my Renderer overrides from being triggered, since Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Renderer is only triggered with Server-side compilation.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to understand some additional logic related to this renderer.

Firstly see `vendor/magento/module-developer/etc/di.xml`

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <!-- ... -->
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="pageConfigRendererFactory" xsi:type="object">Magento\Developer\Model\View\Page\Config\RendererFactory</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <!-- ... -->
    <type name="Magento\Developer\Model\View\Page\Config\RendererFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="rendererTypes" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="client_side_compilation" xsi:type="string">Magento\Developer\Model\View\Page\Config\ClientSideLessCompilation\Renderer</item>
                <item name="server_side_compilation" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Renderer</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <!-- ... -->
</config>
```

If you'll check a logic implemented in `\Magento\Developer\Model\View\Page\Config\RendererFactory::create` you can see that Magento uses 2 different workflow depends on state mode, etc.

You can continue to use `preference` for `Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Renderer`, but you are need to add additional `preference` for `Magento\Developer\Model\View\Page\Config\ClientSideLessCompilation\Renderer`

The alternative way is set your custom renders to `Magento\Developer\Model\View\Page\Config\RendererFactory`